# Is there a way to create a cache or synchronize project online (office 365 tenant) with on-prem project online instance using local data gateway?

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, office365, ms-project, data-gateway

I'm using a project online setup with data in my online office 365 tenant. I have some projects in this tenant. And I have created reports for this in Power BI.

My login for online uses email id: name@anotherdomain_name.com
My on-prem uses: domain_name/users (windows authentication)

Now, I would like to synchronize this data with my on-prem project server setup.

Office 365 tenant cloud and on-prem setup have different login accounts. And are hosted on different servers. So to bridge this I installed a local data gateway inside my on-prem setup.

But the setup became too complex and I fail to understand how to transport the data now.

1. How can I transport my project online data in cloud to project online in on-prem?
2. How can I sybchronize my powerbi data from cloud to power bi report server? I would like to simply synchronize and create a cache of the cloud data in on-prem setup.
3. How should I use my gateway to bridge cloud and on-prem? Because my current installation and setup doesn't synchronize the data to on-prem instance yet. I tested the connection it works.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the Data Gateway/Power BI questions:

> How can I synchronise my powerbi data from cloud to power bi report
>   server? I would like to simply synchronise and create a cache of the
>   cloud data in on-prem setup.

You can't create a copy/replicate the Power BI cloud service data set in you on-prem and sync the two, you'll have to recreate the query for reports hosted in Power BI Report Server or use the the cloud dataset in your Report Server reports.

> How should I use my gateway to bridge cloud and on-prem? Because my
>   current installation and setup doesn't synchronize the data to on-prem
>   instance yet. I tested the connection it works.

The Power BI Enterprise/Personal Gateway doesn't allow sync'ing like this. It is a Read path from On-Prem to the cloud service, you cannot sync data up and down it. It sends a query from the cloud down to the on-prem data source, not data. It sends data to the cloud that is a request of a query, be it direct query or a scheduled refresh of a dataset/dataflow.

Comment: Thanks. For first answer - So you mean that I should upload the pbix file in report server to have it and there is no other way to get this data directly from power bi cloud service? For second answer- So Gateway will only get data from project online or on-prem database or sharepoint based on report query from power bi service in cloud?

Comment: For the first answer - yes thats right. For the data gateway - You will not need it azure based and O365 items (there might be some exclusions to that), its for on-prem items like hosted db's and SharePoint self hosted, Files on a network etc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-gateway-onprem